# Syntax to use form_alter with array in name attribute

Tags: 8, forms

I would like to modify some custom fields with form_alter in a contact form.

I know for example how to change `placeholder` for this "name" field  :
Note : I removed all the unnecessary html elements to make my question clearer

```
<input name="name" >
```

In `form_alter` :

```
$form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Nom');
$form['name']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
```

But I don’t find the correct syntax when the name is with an array like :

```
<input name="field_prenom[0][value]" >
```

How to use `form_alter` with `field_prenom[0][value]` ?

I’ve tried this but it doesn’t work :

```
$form['field_prenom']['0']['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Prénom');
```

Comment: Always only pass English strings to the t-function.

Comment: @leymannx So if I need to add a custom French text, I just need to do `$form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = 'Nom';`?

Comment: Yes, or `t('Name')` and then translate that in the backend as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using field's attribute 'name' instead of it's machine name 'field_prenom'? If you check in 'kint' you would get the hierarchy of 'placeholder' attribute.

You can update placeholder using `form_alter` only. Check the below example.

`$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#placeholder'] = 'Nom';`